# admob ads get shown only once

Tags: kotlin, admob, ads, interstitial

i have admob interstitial ad in my activity .
my ad gets shown only once when button is clicked but does not show when user comes back to same activity

how do i implement interstitial ad to be shown when the activity opens?
my code works only when the show() is added in Onclicklistner.

here is my code

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
    lateinit var profileimage:ImageView
    lateinit var username:EditText
    lateinit var cityname:EditText
    lateinit var aboutMe:EditText
    lateinit var addbutton:ImageButton
    lateinit var saveProfileImage:Button
    var GALLERY_IMAGE =0
      var ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
        val h = supportActionBar
        h!!.title = "My Profile"
        profileimage=findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile)
        aboutMe=findViewById(R.id.aboutId)
        addbutton=findViewById(R.id.addprofilepic)
        saveProfileImage=findViewById(R.id.Saveprofileimage)
        username = findViewById(R.id.usernameId)
        cityname =findViewById(R.id.cityId)
        addbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val z =Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
           z.type=("image/*")
            startActivityForResult(z,GALLERY_IMAGE)
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                mInterstitialAd.show()
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
            }
        }


        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511712")
        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
//        mInterstitialAd.show()

    }
```

mInterstitialAd.show() does not work when added oncreate but works only in setonclicklistner..
can anyboy explain me why??

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511712")
```

just after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You ad display only once, it happen because you only set it first time without reload the ad again.

You need to add the adListener to reload the ads :

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")

        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

        mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
              override fun onAdClosed() {
                     mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
              }
        }
    }
}
```

If it's still doesn't work, it might be your interstitial is not ready yet to display. You could check if it ready by doing this :

```
mMyButton.setOnClickListener {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
        mInterstitialAd.show()
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!